Mock static method of object in react jest
I want to mock a static method defined outside a component.
Here is my component:
import Authenticate from '/api/Authenticate';
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    if (Authenticate.hasGroup()) {
      return (<div>Has group</div>);
    } else {
      return (<div>No group</div>);
    }
  }
}

hasGroup is a static method defined in Authenticate and returns boolean.
Here is my test file
describe('Has Group', () => {
  jest.doMock('/api/Authenticate', () => ({
      __esModule:true,
      hasGroup: jest.fn(()=>true)
    });
  );
  
  it('render has group', ()=>{
    const wrapper = render(<MyComponent/>);
    expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
  })
}

When I run the test, hasGroup method is not mocked. What am I missing?
